# Beautifulsoup not returning complete HTML of the webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get the entire html text of this website.

It only returns the outermost content and all the **inner main content** of the website is not in it..

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = requests.get('https://oldschool.tools/calculators/quest-planner#').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Any support regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: Does the outer content include a `<frame>` element?

Comment: Yes, it contains <iframe> element

Comment: Slightly yes, thanks

Comment: What do you want to fetch from url??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is stored inside javascript variable on that page. To parse the data (and create pandas dataframe form it) you can use this example:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://oldschool.tools/calculators/quest-planner#"
html = requests.get(url).text

data = re.search(r"window\.questData = ({.*})", html).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

df = pd.json_normalize(data.values())
df.index = data.keys()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                    name    difficulty          length  qp skillRequirements                                  questRequirements  qpRequirement  membersOnly  skillRequirements.mining  skillRequirements.crafting  skillRequirements.woodcutting  skillRequirements.cooking  skillRequirements.fishing  skillRequirements.herblore  skillRequirements.prayer  skillRequirements.smithing  skillRequirements.magic  skillRequirements.thieving  skillRequirements.ranged  skillRequirements.attack  skillRequirements.firemaking  skillRequirements.agility  skillRequirements.fletching  skillRequirements.strength  skillRequirements.defence  skillRequirements.slayer  skillRequirements.farming  skillRequirements.runecrafting  skillRequirements.wooductting  skillRequirements.construction  skillRequirements.hunter  skillRequirements.hitpoints
1                       Cook's Assistant        Novice           Short   1                []                                                 []            NaN            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
2                           Demon Slayer        Novice          Medium   3                []                                                 []            NaN            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
3                     The Restless Ghost        Novice           Short   1                []                                                 []            NaN            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
4                         Romeo & Juliet        Novice           Short   5                []                                                 []            NaN            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
5                          Sheep Shearer        Novice           Short   1                []                                                 []            NaN            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
6                        Shield of Arrav        Novice          Medium   1                []                                                 []            NaN            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
7                     Ernest the Chicken        Novice           Short   4                []                                                 []            NaN            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
8                         Vampyre Slayer        Novice           Short   3                []                                                 []            NaN            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
9                            Imp Catcher        Novice           Short   1                []                                                 []            NaN            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
10                     Prince Ali Rescue        Novice           Short   3                []                                                 []            NaN            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
11                         Doric's Quest        Novice           Short   1               NaN                                                 []            NaN            0                      15.0                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
12               Black Knights' Fortress        Novice           Short   3                []                                                 []           12.0            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN
13                        Witch's Potion        Novice           Short   1                []                                                 []            NaN            0                       NaN                         NaN                            NaN                        NaN                        NaN                         NaN                       NaN                         NaN                      NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                           NaN                        NaN                          NaN                         NaN                        NaN                       NaN                        NaN                             NaN                            NaN                             NaN                       NaN                          NaN


...and so on.
```

Comment: I did not know it can be stored in such a manner. Thankyou!